# Set and handle http timeouts in express / node.js

Tags: node.js, http, express, timeout

There's very little documentation and reasoning on how to handle and set http timeouts in express.

I think they can be set via:

```
req.connection.setTimeout(600000);
```

**Update:** I got this working to set it, confirmed.

But after this limit, the server comes back with "No data received". I tried this module [express-timeout](https://github.com/tommydudebreaux/express-timeout) and it didn't work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What behavior do you want when timeout is exceeded?

Here's the documentation for timeout: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/timeout.html

Are you sure you don't want something like sockets.io that would enable connections to be kept alive and reinitiated as needed?